# Windows 2012 server Apache 2.4.10 x64 VC14 HTTP2 Memory Hike to the max why?

Tags: windows, apache, apache2, httpd.conf, apache2.4

My environment is:

1. Windows 2012 Server.
2. Apache 2.4.10 x64 VC14 build from Apache Lounge

All run fine with HTTP and HTTPS except that when I upgraded it to HTTPS 2, the Apache process memory usage hikes up in about a day to the server max like 48gb using 100% of the server memory. My config for the HTTP2 related part in the virtual host is below

```
ProtocolsHonorOrder On  
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1 
H2Direct on
SSLCompression Off  
H2MaxSessionStreams 100
H2SessionExtraFiles 10
H2MaxWorkerIdleSeconds 300
H2MaxWorkers 100    
H2MinWorkers 10
```

Any suggestion where it is wrong ?